# Overheating issues

Tags: honda, accord, overheating, water-pump

92'honda accord
New radiator, radiator hoses, thermostat, thermostat housing, waterpump
Idles fines overheats when driven. Blowing holes in hoses of thermostat housing. Tested 1st and 2nd thermostat and both are good.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but to your description it sounds like a Blown Head gasket. First make sure the Fan(s) are operating as required. There are a few small indications to check for possible Head Gasket issue. 1: Depending how old the Radiator is; check the Cap bottom sealing ring inside the filler neck. Look for eating away of the ring, (hot hydrocarbons will cause this). 2: If the Radiator builds pressure before it has time to warm up is also a sign. A Block Test can be misleading unless you know what to look for.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked everything and your car still overheats, before thinking about head gasket, it is better to perform a complete air bleeding procedure according to manufacturer's recommendation. I have seen many cars that were not bled properly and overheated even if they had done a complete cooling system overhaul.

Answer (score -1):

If your water is circulating, then that leaves two options- you have excessive heat production or your fan is not working effectively. Check your fan, fan clutch, and fan shroud for proper function.